# I want to add json object which is nested in database using volley. I am not able to add this

Tags: android, json, android-volley

This is the type of nested object I want to add :
{
"user_id": 434,
"firstName": "Harry",
"lastName": "Dex",
"userName": "PN1002",
"password": "Reset123",
"role": {
"roleName": "User"
}
}

This is my Main File:

```
EditText firstName, lastName, userName, passWord;
Spinner roleName;
Button submit;
String rolename;
String fName, lName, uName, pass, rName;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
static final String REQ_TAG = "VACTIVITY";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_user);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    firstName = findViewById(R.id.et_fstName);
    lastName =  findViewById(R.id.et_lstName);
    userName =  findViewById(R.id.et_userName);
    passWord = findViewById(R.id.et_passWord);

    roleName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.et_roleName);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("User");
    arrayList.add("Engineer");
    arrayList.add("Team Manager");
    arrayList.add("Worker");
    arrayList.add("Developer");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    roleName.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    roleName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            rolename = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
           // Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + rolename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
            .getRequestQueue();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            fName = firstName.getText().toString();
            lName = lastName.getText().toString();
            uName = userName.getText().toString();
            pass = passWord.getText().toString();
            rName = rolename;

            addUserdata();
        }
    });

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (requestQueue != null) {
        requestQueue.cancelAll(REQ_TAG);
    }
}

public void addUserdata() {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {

        json.put("roleName", rName);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jsonObject.put("role", json);
        jsonObject.put("firstName",fName);
        jsonObject.put("lastName",lName);
        jsonObject.put("userName",uName);
        jsonObject.put("password",pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoint.ADD_USER,jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Toasty.success(AddNewUserActivity.this,"Saved successfully!"+response.get("message").toString(),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AddNewUserActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);



}
```

I am getting warning as:

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for message
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
at com.project.project1.myapplication2.Activities.AddNewUserActivity$3.onResponse(AddNewUserActivity.java:143)
at com.project.project1.myapplication2.Activities.AddNewUserActivity$3.onResponse(AddNewUserActivity.java:139)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)

Answer (score 0):

your `rolename` is `null` untill you select it from the `spinner` that means your `rName` is also `null` initially which is throwing the error. try setting it to some value before even clicking the `spinner`

Comment: then in your json response there's no `message` key which is you are trying to get. check what your server is sending back really. you can use tools like postman